# android horizontal and vertical layout in one file

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I know that the default way to provide vertical and horizontal layout is to create two xml files, one in layout and second in layout-land dirs.

However when I have very big layout where only very small part will be orientation depended, I would prefer to avoid creating two files as it can be difficult to keep them synchronized (ex. I will change something in one, and will forget to change in the second one).

I was wondering if there is perhaps any other way, ex. something like:

```
common part

if orientation==vertical

part of xml vertical layout definition

if orientation==horizontal

part of xml horizontal layout definition

common part
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Make a single layout and into the file make two parrent views one visible and one gone and use

```
      @Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
            if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {//play with visibilities}
else
{//same
```

}

Comment: Interesting idea, but if I use the same component id's, it will lead to problems.... If I use different ones, I will have to double them in my code....

Comment: will double them but avoid a lots of problems

Comment: This is my solution as well (but you should use the supported framework for this, instead of working around it).

Comment: the best way to learn something is not to copy paste... is to think in your context

Answer (score 1):

What about using the `<include>` tag in your layout? This would end up creating three XML files, the one "big" one that is applicable for all orientations, and then one smaller landscape and one smaller portrait XML layout for just the part that is different for each orientation.

See [Layout Resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/layout-resource.html) for more info on `<include>`

Comment: I haven't checked yet if it works, but this seems to be the solution I'm looking for....

Answer (score 0):

Create your Layout elements (RelativeLayout or LinearLayout, whichever you are using) in your single layout file.  Then control their visibility in code depending on orientation.

(This way I propose will work, but you are way better off using the resource framework Android provides for this - instead of side-stepping it like you are proposing - however this is not your question)

Like this pseudo-code:

```
<LinearLayout>
     <!-- Horizontal Layout -->
     <RelativeLayout 
         android:visibility="gone" />

     <!-- Vertical Layout -->
     <RelativeLayout
          android:visibility="visible" />
</LinearLayout>
```

then in Java:

```
if (horizontal) {
   horizView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   vertView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```